# uniq in underscore.js is not working

Tags: underscore.js

Kindly check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattmorz/8r6ye78g/), `uniq()` function has no effect. Tried separating the function but still unable to work it out. The JSON was flattened first then I used `uniq`.

Comment: Uniq uses === to test for equality. For objects this will only return true if the operands refer to the same object. In the fiddle all the objects are different objects hence uniq appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Underscore.js documentation:

> Uniq
>   Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.

So you can try and use a function to transform the object into a comparable value. For example:

```
var res = _.chain(data)
    .flatten()
    .uniq(function(v){ return v.mycount + v.mytype })
    .value();
```